# Evaluate the limit of $ \sum_{j=n}^{2n} {n \over \sqrt{n^4 + j^2} }$ when n→∞

Tags: calculus

I tried to use the squeeze theorem I got to:

right side:

$ \sum_{j=n}^{2n} {n \over \sqrt{n^4 + j^2} }< {\sqrt n^4 \over \sqrt{n^4} } \longrightarrow 1$

I think the limit is $1$ . Fix me if I'm wrong please
Having troubles finding the left side I get to $\sqrt {1 \over 2}$ I think I decrease the exp too much.

edit: I tried to see what's the limit using Wolfarm but it doesn't work

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging in the upper and lower bounds for $j$, we have $$(n+1)\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^4 +4n^2}}\right) \le \sum^{2n}_{j=n} \frac n {\sqrt{n^4 + j^2}} \le (n+1)\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^4 +n^2}}\right)$$ whence the squeeze theorem tells us that the limit is indeed $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using User8128's answer, you could also see how is approached the limit.

Using the generalized binomial theorem or, even better, Taylor expansions for infinitely large values of $n$, you would get $$(n+1)\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^4 +4n^2}}\right)=1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ $$(n+1)\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^4 +n^2}}\right)=1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ showing the limit and making then $$\sum^{2n}_{j=n} \frac n {\sqrt{n^4 + j^2}}=1+\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Using $n=10$, the exact value is $\approx 1.00988$ while, truncated to $O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$, the above expansions give $1.00980$ and $1.00995$.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Is there any other main methods that I can realize what the limit is? I'm always guessing

Comment: For this specific type of problems, bounding followed by the squeeze theorem (as done by User8128) is the simplest for sure. But, there are so many different problems ... !

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes I'm getting confused while bounding because I increase/decrease the expression too much and make mistakes If I only had an indicator of what the limit is I would have known when I'm increasing too much

Comment: Do you know the integral test ? Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: not yet unfortuneately

Comment: @user21312. Don't worry ! This will come soon. It is a very good one. Cheers.